# Just recieve one Dataobject from JSON

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i try to get Map Markers from JSON into a MapActivity.
i just get the first one from the JSON the others arent shown in my map.
how can i solve my problem.
Here is my Map Activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private static String url="http://partypeople.bplaced.net/markers.json";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
double latitude;
double longitude;
String namec;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map3);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("markers");


                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String lat = c.getString("lat");
                    String lng = c.getString("lng");




                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("address",address);
                    contact.put("lat", lat);
                    contact.put("lng", lng);

                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat); longitude = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                    namec = name;


                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

            LatLng P1 = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P1).title(namec));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(P1));

    }

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    new GetContacts().execute();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);





}
```

}

and here is my JSON:

```
{
"markers": [

    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Munic",
            "address": "try",
            "lat": "48.142281",
            "lng" : "11.550613"


    },
   {
            "id": "c205",
            "name": "Berlin",
            "address": "test",
            "lat": "43.142281",
            "lng" : "11.550613"


    }
```

]
}

and here is my httpHandler:

public class HttpHandler {

```
private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

public HttpHandler() {
}

public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in onPostExecute, you add only one marker to map.
You should use your contactList there:

```
for (HashMap<String, String> contact: contactList) {
    LatLng P1 = new LatLng(
                    Double.parseDouble(contact.get("lat")),
                    Double.parseDouble(contact.get("lng")));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P1).title(contact.get("name")));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(P1));
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt run, there is just one marker shown

Comment: Sorry, now its working fine i had a secon mistake :)